# Having issues when making list an instance of a type class

Tags: haskell, computer-science, typeclass

I have made a type class and made list an instance of type class but I am getting an error which I do not understand

```
class MyType a where
listsum:: a->a->Double

instance (Num a)=>MyType [a] where
    listsum x y = sum $ zipWith (-) x y
```

listsum returns a single value but this is the error I get:

```
 Could not deduce (a ~ Double)
from the context (Num a)
  bound by the instance declaration at b2.hs:4:10-28
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
      the instance declaration at b2.hs:4:10
In the expression: sum $ zipWith (-) x y
In an equation for `listsum': listsum x y = sum $ zipWith (-) x y
In the instance declaration for `MyType [a]'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Let's write down some annotations.

```
sum     :: (Num a, Foldable t) => t a -> a
zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
(-)     :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

Let's derive the type of `\ x y -> sum $ zipWith (-) x y`.

```
-- 1. Let's substitute (-) to zipWith:

zipWith (-) :: Num a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]

-- 2. Let's substitute `(zipWith (-))` to `sum`. We can't
-- write it point free like in `zipWith (-)` case. So we add
-- two extra params:

(\ x y -> sum $ zipWith (-) x y) :: Num a => [a] -> [a] -> a
```

The type of `listsum` for `[a]` is:

```
listsum :: (Num a) => [a] -> [a] -> Double
```

It takes two lists of something of `(Num a => a)` and
returns `Double`. But `(\ x y -> sum $ zipWith (-) x y)`
returns any `(Num a => a)`. The compiler cannot be sure
that this `(Num a => a)` will always be `Double`. That's why you
get the error:

```
Could not deduce (a ~ Double) from the context (Num a)
```

@sclv gave you two options to solve it. Another one is
to change the `MyType` class to

```
class MyType a where
    listsum:: [a] -> [a] -> a
```

so that the `listsum` and `(\ x y -> sum $ zipWith (-) x y)` has the same type.

It also gives you an opportunity to parametrize `listsum` by a type of elements of list.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify `listsum:: a -> a -> Double` to be `listsum :: [a] -> [a] -> a` and declare your instance over `a` rather than `[a]` *Or* you can modify your instance from `instance (Num a) => MyType [a]` to `instance MyType [Double]`.

You can see the error by just taking the type of the expression `\x y -> sum $ zipWith (-) x y`. You will see that it is `Num a => [a] -> [a] -> a` and not `Num a => [a] -> [a] -> Double` as your class currently requires.